# How to find min and max using STL algorithms?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have `resturent` and `ratings`. How can I use STL containers to find the min and max of the restaurant rating? Will I need to use the STL algorithm of maximum and minimum rating? I will have to find the average rating using any methods.

```
Id  Name
1   McDonalds 
2   Wendys 
3   Burger King

Id  Resturent Rating
1     100
2     90
3     85
1     80
2     90
3     100
1     85
2     75
3     100




int main {

  map<int, string> resturent;

  stu.insert(pair<int, string>(1,  "McDonalds")));
  stu.insert(pair<int, string>(2, "Wendys")));
  stu.insert(pair<int, string>(3,"Burger King")));

  multimap<int, int> rating;
  testScore.insert(pair<int, int>(1, 10));
  testScore.insert(pair<int, int>(2, 9));
  testScore.insert(pair<int, int>(3, 8));
  testScore.insert(pair<int, int>(1, 8));
  testScore.insert(pair<int, int>(2, 6));
  testScore.insert(pair<int, int>(3, 10));
  testScore.insert(pair<int, int>(1, 5));
  testScore.insert(pair<int, int>(2, 7));
  testScore.insert(pair<int, int>(3, 9));
}
```

Expected Answer:

```
Resturent:McDonalds Id:1
Max Rating: 10
Min Rating: 5
Average Rating:7.67
```

Comment: @salmankhan Why this odd design?  I think it would make more sense for a `Student` to contain a `std::vector<int>` to denote the test scores, along with the id and name.  Having the test scores in another map makes this more difficult than it should be.

Comment: `class Student { int id; string name; std::vector<int> testscores; };` -- Is there a reason why you couldn't use that simple design?

Comment: Requirements by teachers are getting stranger and stranger as the years go on.  Instead of teaching how to properly design programs, these strange and unorthodox "requirements" keep cropping up.  It's almost like a conspiracy to have students hate C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie's suggestion can be done with two containers. The first is a `vector<Student>` which has one entry for each student and the second is the `vector<int>` which has the scores for each test each student takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the following class, `Ratings` for retrieving the statistics of a restaurant's ratings:

```
#include <limits>

class Ratings {
   unsigned num_{0};  // number of ratings inserted
   long long sum_{0}; // sum of all the inserted ratings
   int min_{std::numeric_limits<int>::max()};
   int max_{std::numeric_limits<int>::min()};

public:
   void insert_rating(int rating) {
      // update minimum
      if (rating < min_)
         min_ = rating;

      // update maximum
      if (rating > max_)
         max_ = rating;

      // update sum
      sum_ += rating;

      // update number of ratings
      num_++;
   }

   double average() const {
      // calculate the average rating
      return (double)sum_ / num_; 
   }

   int min() const { return min_; }
   int max() const { return max_; }
};
```

It keeps tracks of the minimum, the maximum, the sum and the number of ratings inserted. Therefore, obtaining the minimum, the maximum and the average is done in constant time. Adding a rating is also done in constant time since it just requires a constant number of operations, i.e., updating `min_`, `max_`, `sum_` and `num_`.

Then, you need a `Rating` object for each restaurant to be rated, i.e., for each element in the `restaurant` map. You can have a vector of `Rating`s of the same size as the `restaurant` map, and use the (zero-based) restaurant's id for indexing the elements in the vector:

```
int main() {
   // id to restaurant
   std::map<int, std::string> restaurant;

   restaurant.insert({0, "McDonalds"});
   restaurant.insert({1, "Wendys"});
   restaurant.insert({2, "Burger King"});

   // a Ratings object for each restaurant
   std::vector<Ratings> ratings(restaurant.size());

   ratings[0].insert_rating(10);
   ratings[1].insert_rating(9);
   ratings[2].insert_rating(8);
   ratings[0].insert_rating(8);
   ratings[1].insert_rating(6);
   ratings[2].insert_rating(10);
   ratings[0].insert_rating(5);
   ratings[1].insert_rating(7);
   ratings[2].insert_rating(9);

   for (int i = 0; i < ratings.size(); ++i) {
      std::cout << "Restaurant: " << restaurant[i] << ", Id: " << i << '\n';
      std::cout << "Max Rating: " << ratings[i].max() << '\n';
      std::cout << "Min Rating: " << ratings[i].min() << '\n';
      std::cout << "Average Rating: " << ratings[i].average() << '\n';
      std::cout << '\n';
   }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Restaurant: McDonalds, Id: 0
Max Rating: 10
Min Rating: 5
Average Rating: 7.66667

Restaurant: Wendys, Id: 1
Max Rating: 9
Min Rating: 6
Average Rating: 7.33333

Restaurant: Burger King, Id: 2
Max Rating: 10
Min Rating: 8
Average Rating: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to show you one possible solution. There are many . . .

My guess is that the teacher requested 2 separate containers, because he may want to explain databases later, where we have a parent table "Student" with the primary key "id" and a related child table "Score" with the foreign key "id" (not NULL).

Ok, then let's take this approach. We create 2 classes: "Student" and "Score". We build vectors of it. Then we have a table (vector) with attributes. The class members are the attributes of the table. The tables are initialized with some test values.

To show all calculated values for all students, we iterate over the "students" table with the range based for loop. Then we filter the "scores" table, for the current evaluated student **id**. This is similar to a database where clause with a sub query.

Anyway. We will have then a table, containing only the scores for this student. Then we use standard algorithms for STL containers, like [std::min_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element), [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). The `std::accumulate` is used to calculate the average. So, sum of values divided by number of values.

For the algorithms we use lambdas to access to correct elements.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <numeric>

struct Student
{
    unsigned int id{};
    std::string name{};

};
struct Score
{
    unsigned int id{};
    unsigned int score{};
};

std::vector<Student> students{ {1U,"John"},{2U,"Mary"},{3U,"Luke"},{4U,"Lisa"} };
std::vector<Score> scores{ {3U,100U},{4U,80U},{2U,90U},{1U,85U},{1U,95U},{2U,90U},{3U,80U},
                           {4U,95U},{3U,100U},{1U,80U},{2U,85U},{3U,95U},{1U,95U},{2U,100U},{3U,95U} };

int main()
{
    // Calculating all results
    for (const Student& student : students) {

        // Filter out the scores for this student
        std::vector<Score> scoreForThisStudent{};
        std::copy_if(scores.begin(), scores.end(), std::back_inserter(scoreForThisStudent), [&student](const Score & s) { return student.id == s.id; });

        // Check, if scores are available. Calculate only in this case
        if (scoreForThisStudent.size()) {
            std::cout << "\nStudent\nID: " << std::left << std::setw(4) << student.id << "    Name: " << student.name
                << "\nMin Score:        " << std::min_element(scoreForThisStudent.begin(), scoreForThisStudent.end(), [](const Score & s1, const Score & s2) {return s1.score < s2.score; })->score
                << "\nMax Score:        " << std::max_element(scoreForThisStudent.begin(), scoreForThisStudent.end(), [](const Score & s1, const Score & s2) {return s1.score < s2.score; })->score
                << "\nNumber of Scores: " << scoreForThisStudent.size()
                << "\nAverage:          " << std::accumulate(scoreForThisStudent.begin(), scoreForThisStudent.end(), 0U, [](const unsigned int s1, const Score & s2) {return s1 + s2.score; }) / scoreForThisStudent.size() << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Becuase of the somehow tedious work to write lambdas, we make one small improvement and overload the "<" and "+" operator of our Score class. With that there is no need for lambdas and the std::algorithms will directly use the operators from the class.

Please see:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <numeric>

struct Student
{
    unsigned int id{};
    std::string name{};

};
struct Score
{
    unsigned int id{};
    unsigned int score{};
    bool operator < (const Score& other) const { return score < other.score; }
    friend unsigned int operator + (const unsigned int val, const Score& other) { return val + other.score; }
};

std::vector<Student> students{ {1U,"John"},{2U,"Mary"},{3U,"Luke"},{4U,"Lisa"} };
std::vector<Score> scores{ {3U,100U},{4U,80U},{2U,90U},{1U,85U},{1U,95U},{2U,90U},{3U,80U},
                           {4U,95U},{3U,100U},{1U,80U},{2U,85U},{3U,95U},{1U,95U},{2U,100U},{3U,95U} };

int main()
{
    // Calculating all results
    for (const Student& student : students) {

        // Filter out the scores for this student
        std::vector<Score> scoreForThisStudent{};
        std::copy_if(scores.begin(), scores.end(), std::back_inserter(scoreForThisStudent), [&student](const Score &s) { return student.id == s.id; });

        // Check, if scores are available. Calculate only in this case
        if (scoreForThisStudent.size()) {
            // Calculate all required values
            std::cout << "\nStudent\nID: " << std::left << std::setw(4) << student.id << "    Name: " << student.name
                << "\nMin Score:        " << std::min_element(scoreForThisStudent.begin(), scoreForThisStudent.end())->score
                << "\nMax Score:        " << std::max_element(scoreForThisStudent.begin(), scoreForThisStudent.end())->score
                << "\nNumber of Scores: " << scoreForThisStudent.size() 
                << "\nAverage:          " << std::accumulate(scoreForThisStudent.begin(), scoreForThisStudent.end(), 0U) / scoreForThisStudent.size() << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps to get a better understanding

Comment: *My guess is that the teacher requested 2 separate containers, because he may want to explain databases later* -- If that's the case, what a roundabout way of getting to discussing databases.  Use bad C++ design to explain database tables.  Wow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **min_element(start_iterator, end_iterator)** and **max_element(start_iterator, end_iterator)** respectively which returns an iterator to the  largest value in the range. Here you go!!!

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>    

using namespace std;

int main () {
  int myints[] = {3,7,2,5,6,4,9};

  //Method 1
  int minElement = *min_element(myints, myints+7);
  int maxElement = *max_element(myints, myints+7);      
  cout<<"Max: "<< maxElement <<"\n";
  cout<<"Min: "<< minElement <<"\n";


  // Method 2: added by @HolyBlackCat
  int result = minmax_element(myints, myints+7);   //return a pair with iterator pointing to minimum element
  cout<<"Max: "<< *result.first <<"\n";
  cout<<"Min: "<< *result.second <<"\n";


  // Method 3:
  int result = minmax(myints, myints+7);   //return a pair of min,max element
  cout<<"Max: "<< result.first <<"\n";
  cout<<"Min: "<< result.second <<"\n";


  return 0;
}
```

**PS: element pointed by the last_iterator is not included. i.e it is exclusive on the upper bound.**

Comment: This traverses the array twice, which is not a good thing. Better use `minmax_element`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for adding this new method. I will try using it in my codes as well.